# Selenium webdriver error Chrome failed to start

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open Chrome webdriver through Selenium and I'm getting an error when initializing it. The error I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\WinPython\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "F:\WinPython\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "F:\WinPython\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "F:\WinPython\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\WinPython\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\some-ever-changing-hash\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesX86\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I've been searching for different solutions. I've tried manually specifying path to Chrome.exe, I've added snippets like `add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")` and `options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")` as well as using separate user-data-dir. Current code can be seen below

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

###auto-find chrome path
def chrome_path_auto():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users'):
        for name in files:
            if name == 'chrome.exe':
                return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_driver_binary = "H:/My Documents/PYTHON/selenium_script/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
options.binary_location = chrome_path_auto()
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=H:\\My Documents\\PYTHON\\selenium_script\\UserDataDir")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://python.org')
```

Version of Chrome is 71.0.3578.80, Chromedriver is 2.45, so it should be compatible. I've tried using older versions but then I get only part of the error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist. 
It might be important to note that I am using a remote desktop that very recently changed OS from Windows 7 to Windows 10. On the old windows a very similar approach (using older versions of both Chrome and Chromedriver) was working. Did anyone encounter similar issue or can think of of alternative solutions?

If anything else is needed please tell me, I'll try to provide such info.

**EDIT 1.**

I have managed to fix the problem by simply moving whole Chrome installation from original folder 
`C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\some-ever-changing-hash\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesX86\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` to the shared disk `H:\Public\Chrome\Application` and then using binary_location. It might have to do something with the Root location of original folder and lack of admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the DevToolsActivePort issue try adding the following argument:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=45447')
```

Basically once the port is set to something other than the default of 0 the DevToolsActivePort file does not need to be checked thus avoiding your issue. Some more details on the DevToolsActivePort issue can be found here: [chromedriver_bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2161#c57)

From what I have experienced of this issue, it seems to occur when the user profiles are copied outside of chromes default folder usually located here:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, that didn't work but I've managed to resolve issue. I'll write an answer soon

Comment: @Seidhe I could really use that answer...